# how to send worksheet data static in PHPExcel chart

Tags: php, phpexcel

i took example from 33chartcreate-pie.php from PHPExcel-1.8 and changing according to my need. now that example have x-axis value like.

```
$xAxisTickValues1 = array(
new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$5', NULL, 4),  //  Q1 to Q4
);
```

now, i want add it static as PASS and FAIL so, i try it like

```
$xAxisTickValues1 = array(
new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'PASS:FAIL', NULL, 2),    //  Q1 to Q4
);
```

but, it is not working. how to put static value in that array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example which you follow :

```
$xAxisTickValues1 = array(
new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$5', NULL, 4),  //  Q1 to Q4
);
```

Here Worksheet is the title of the sheet. So while plotting graph it will read value from the specified title followed by Columns as A2 to A5.

If you simply want to add static value. Create cell with static content in it and pass the cell index to data series values.

Answer (score 1):

We need to show static labels in cells to show them on graph or PIE chart. 
While ploting graph we can show and hide labels or values using functions like setShowVal, setShowCatName.

```
  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
  $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
  $objWorksheet->fromArray(
    array(
      array('', 2010,   2011,   2012),
      array('PASS',   12,   15,     21),
      array('FAIL',   56,   73,     86)
    )
  );

  $dataSeriesLabels1 = array(
     new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$C$1',    NULL, 1),   //  2011
  );

  $xAxisTickValues1 = array(
     new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$3', NULL, 2), //  Q1 to Q4
  );

  $dataSeriesValues1 = array(
     new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$3', NULL, 2),
  );

  //    Build the dataseries
  $series1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
   PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_PIECHART,                //   plotType
  NULL,                                                 //   plotGrouping (Pie charts don't have any grouping)
  range(0, count($dataSeriesValues1)-1),                    // plotOrder
  $dataSeriesLabels1,                                       // plotLabel
  $xAxisTickValues1,                                        // plotCategory
  $dataSeriesValues1                                        // plotValues
  );

  //    Set up a layout object for the Pie chart
  $layout1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Layout();
  /*$layout1->setShowVal(TRUE);*/
  $layout1->setShowCatName(TRUE);

   //   Set the series in the plot area
   $plotArea1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea($layout1, array($series1));
   //   Set the chart legend
   $legend1 = new      PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);

   $title1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Pie Chart');


   //   Create the chart
   $chart1 = new PHPExcel_Chart(
     'chart1',      // name
     $title1,       // title
     $legend1,      // legend
     $plotArea1,        // plotArea
     true,          // plotVisibleOnly
     0,             // displayBlanksAs
     NULL,          // xAxisLabel
     NULL           // yAxisLabel       - Pie charts don't have a Y-Axis
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your array of declaration like

```
array(
        array('',   2010,   2011,   2012),
        array('Q1',   12,   15,     21),
        array('Pass or fail',   56,   73,   86)
        )
```

. This is how you can set a static value. 
Now to display it , you can add a property to your layout to show your categoryname for the chart with `->setShowCatName(TRUE);`